# Bootstrap input wrong display with prepopulated data

Tags: css, grails, bootstrap-4

I'm having this problem with Bootstrap inputs when a record is called for edition:
[image]

My code to define inputs:

```
    <div class="card card-frame">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: materialInstance, field: 'nombre', 'error')} required">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-outline my-1">
                            <label class="form-label"><g:message code="material.nombre.label" default="Nombre" /></label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="nombre" required="" value="${materialInstance?.nombre}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <hr>
    
                <div class="row fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: materialInstance, field: 'cantidadMinima1', 'error')} required">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-outline my-1">
                            <label class="form-label"><g:message code="material.cantidadMinima1.label" default="Nombre" /></label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="cantidadMinima1" required="" value="${materialInstance?.cantidadMinima1}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
      ...
      ...
      </div>
    </div>
```

I've googled and found there's a class called `is-filled` but when applied nothing changes. Am I missing something to have inputs like this?
[image]

I'm using this Bootstrap-based components: https://www.creative-tim.com/learning-lab/bootstrap/forms/material-dashboard